# InvalidArgumentException View [auth.login] not found

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

InvalidArgumentException
View [auth.login] not found.

I try to create my own authentification (beginner)
I try to create my own authentification (beginner)
I try to create my own authentification (beginner)
I try to create my own authentification (beginner)

Page Controller :

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view('/login');
    }
    public function acc(){
        return view('/accounts/account');
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public function signAdmin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'IdAdmin'=>'required|email|max:255',
        'PasswordAdmin'=>'required|max:255',
    ]);
    if(Auth::attempt(['IdAdmin'=>$request->email,'PasswordAdmin'=>$request->password])){
        return 'login success';
    }   
    else{
        return 'error';
    }
    return redirect()->route('/accueil');
    /*$user = DB::table('admin')->where('IdAdmin', $request->IdAdmin)->first();

    if ($user->IdAdmin === $request->Admin) {
        return redirect('/accounts/account');
    } 
    else {
        return back()->with('error', 'Your credentials dont match our records');
    }*/
}
```

Page master :

```
<div class="navbar">
   
    <a href="{{url('/accueil')}}" class="logo">RABAT</a>
    <ul class="nav">
         @if (Route::has('login'))
            <li><a href="{{url('/accueil')}}">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{url('/contact')}}">Contact Us</a></li>
            @auth  
                <li><a href="{{url('/account')}}">Account</a></li>
            @else
                <li><a href="{{url('/login')}}">Log In</a></li>
            @endauth
        @endif
        
    </ul>
</div><br><br><br><br>
@yield('content')
```

Comment: Do you have this page on on this location `.../views/auth/login.blade.php`?

Comment: i removed it i want to create my own auth without command's blade !

Comment: Then your blade still extend it or your controller.

Comment: so what i should remove please? the default page 'welcome.blade' i removed the auth code?